# Django no PUT method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with my django rest framework views. The PUT method is calling a GET instead. So I cannot update any objects. Some views were working and now there are not.Here an example of view:

```
    class BiduleEditView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
      """A view that allows to edit a bidule """
        serializer_class = BiduleEditSerializer
        queryset = Bidule.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

Does anybody have an idea ?
            lookup_fields = 'pk'

Here is the corresponding url:

```
    url(r'^bidule/(?P<pk>[a-z0-9\-]+)/edit/$', views.BiduleEditView.as_view()),
```

Here is the serializer:

```
    class BiduleEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         class Meta:
               model=Bidule
               fields = '__all__'
```

I also overrode the put method. It is not working. I wrote a print in the beginning of the put method. There no print in the terminal. That means it not executing the put method.

Comment: Can you explain more when you say PUT method is calling GET. What are you using to try to PUT?

Comment: I just ran the server. And test the url with localhost. I change the data and hit the put button. But in terminal i can see that it was a get method that was initiate

Comment: What program were you using to 'change the data and hit the put button'

Comment: no program. Just the normal restframework interface

Comment: Can you update your question by putting serializers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly put a `put` method into your viewsets like below. From now you can define whatever you want to be done when update an object

```
class BiduleEditView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
        A view that allows to edit a bidule
    """
    serializer_class = BiduleEditSerializer
    queryset = Bidule.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # ... some other methods
```

Comment: That what I did in the first place. So I came back to the generic method.

Comment: So is your problem solved ? Or is there something else ?

Comment: No. It is still there. I don't really get it. The funny thing is that my update views are working for other applications in the project. But for this specific application, I can't update objects.

Comment: I also overrode the put method. It is not working. I wrote a print in the beginning of the put method. There no print in the terminal. That means it not executing the put method.

Comment: It would be a lot better if you expand your question with more data. Serializers and Models I mean. You may also try using ModelViewSet instead of APIView because ViewSet makes things easier in general, and it could make it easier for you to find mistake